# Count values based off of conditions/previous row in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to have R calculate baseball counts, but I'm not quite sure how to properly read the previous rows in order to calculate it. Here's what a simple sample of my dataset looks like with the relevant columns/data:

```
Label <- c("Raul", "Raul", "Raul", "Eric", "Eric", "Eric", "Eric", "Aaron", "Aaron") 
Result <- c("s", "b", "fo", "s", "f", "b", "s", "ss", "go") 
AB.Pitch <- c("1", "2", "3","1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2")
df2 <- data.frame(Label, AB.Pitch, Result)
```

What I want to do is create a new column with the count on that pitch. In this case, it would look like this:

```
Count <- c("00", "01", "11", "00", "01", "02", "12", "00", "01")
```

So, it needs to read the result in the previous row, then calculate the new value of the count based on that and a few other conditions. Every time AB.Pitch == "1", the count should be "00" and the max value the count can reach is "32". The results (s, f, ss) are strikes, therefore going from "00" to "01", etc, whereas "b" should go to "10", etc. Everything else should result in the end of an at-bat and the next AB.Pitch should equal 1, so the count would be "00".

```
df2 <- df2 %>%
mutate(Count2 = ifelse(AB.Pitch == "1", as.numeric("00"), 
                        ifelse(lag(Result) == "s", lag(Count) + 01,
                               ifelse(lag(Result) == "b", lag(Count) + 10))))
```

Here's some code I tried. Going step by step, I had no problem with the first line getting AB.Pitch to = "00", but couldn't get anything after that. This is my first time trying to work with lag so I really appreciate any push in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this might be an alternative to consider. As you have, use `group_by` for each batter's time at the plate. You can keep balls and strikes separate and use `cumsum` to accumulate counts individually. Your `Count` will simply paste the two counts together into a character value.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  group_by(Label) %>%
  mutate(Ball = cumsum(lag(Result, default = "") == "b"),
         Strike = cumsum(lag(Result, default = "") %in% c("s", "f", "ss")),
         Count = paste0(Ball, Strike))
```

**Output**

```
  Label AB.Pitch Result  Ball Strike Count
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>
1 Raul  1        s          0      0 00   
2 Raul  2        b          0      1 01   
3 Raul  3        fo         1      1 11   
4 Eric  1        s          0      0 00   
5 Eric  2        f          0      1 01   
6 Eric  3        b          0      2 02   
7 Eric  4        s          1      2 12   
8 Aaron 1        ss         0      0 00   
9 Aaron 2        go         0      1 01
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea. I summed the points for each player.

```
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Points = case_when(Result == "b" ~ 10,
                            TRUE ~ 1)) %>%
  group_by(Label) %>% 
  mutate(Count = cumsum(lag(Points, default = 0)))


  Label AB.Pitch Result Points Count
  <fct> <fct>    <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Raul  1        s           1     0
2 Raul  2        b          10     1
3 Raul  3        fo          1    11
4 Eric  1        s           1     0
5 Eric  2        f           1     1
6 Eric  3        b          10     2
7 Eric  4        s           1    12
8 Aaron 1        ss          1     0
9 Aaron 2        go          1     1
```